How to add a div below a div that has h-screen as a utility class while maintaining its horizontal and vertical centered state?
I am testing out some tailwind features. As you can see I have successfully centered a div horizontally and vertically:

This is my code for that:
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
      <div>
        <h1 class="text-6xl font-medium">sample</h1>
        <div class="greeting2 text-[100px]">
          <h2 class="text-gradient font-semibold">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>
        <a
          href="#"
          class="animate-fade transition-colors bg-primary hover:bg-primary/90 h-10 inline-flex items-center justify-center px-6 py-2 border-0 rounded-full text-sm font-medium text-white bg-gradient-to-l from-blue-500 to-purple-600 shadow-lg hover:from-purple-500 hover:to-blue-600 mt-0"
        >
          See More
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="../Humaaans/sitting-4.svg" class="animate-fade" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>

The problem is, I tried adding a div right beneath the first div, but it doesn't display:
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
      <div>
        <h1 class="text-6xl font-medium">sample</h1>
        <div class="greeting2 text-[100px]">
          <h2 class="text-gradient font-semibold">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>
        <a
          href="#"
          class="animate-fade transition-colors bg-primary hover:bg-primary/90 h-10 inline-flex items-center justify-center px-6 py-2 border-0 rounded-full text-sm font-medium text-white bg-gradient-to-l from-blue-500 to-purple-600 shadow-lg hover:from-purple-500 hover:to-blue-600 mt-0"
        >
          See More
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="../Humaaans/sitting-4.svg" class="animate-fade" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- this is not being displayed -->
    <div>
        test
    </div>

I know for sure that the problem is the h-screen.
I am new to tailwind CSS and would like to be able to add a div below the first one while maintaining its horizontal and vertical centered state.

If I understand you correctly, you mean you have a card that you want to keep perfectly centered in the viewport, and you also want to add an extra element underneath it.
If so, the first thing you can try is an absolute layout. By adding a wrapping element, you can have an absolute element added to the bottom of the card.
I replaced h-screen with min-h-screen to ensure it displays properly when overflowing:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="flex min-h-screen items-center justify-center">
  <div class="relative">
    <article>
      <div>
        <h1 class="text-6xl font-medium">sample</h1>
        <div class="greeting2 text-[100px]">
          <h2 class="text-gradient font-semibold">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="animate-fade bg-primary hover:bg-primary/90 mt-0 inline-flex h-10 items-center justify-center rounded-full border-0 bg-gradient-to-l from-blue-500 to-purple-600 px-6 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-lg transition-colors hover:from-purple-500 hover:to-blue-600"> See More </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="../Humaaans/sitting-4.svg" class="animate-fade" alt="" />
      </div>
    </article>
    <aside class="h-32 bg-amber-200 absolute top-full inset-x-0"></aside>
  </div>
</div>



(Ensure that the viewport has enough space to view the effect; a small space will cause the card to extend beyond one screen.)
Demo on Tailwind Play

However, absolutely positioned elements will overlap the elements beneath them when the card take up space more than one screen. If you want to display all elements even when there isn't enough space, you shouldn't use absolute positioning.
In this case, I suggest rendering this element twice, once above and once below the card. By hiding the top element so that it only occupies space without being displayed, you can still maintain vertical centering of the card:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="flex min-h-screen items-center justify-center">
  <div>
    <aside class="invisible h-32 bg-amber-200"></aside>
    <article>
      <div>
        <h1 class="text-6xl font-medium">sample</h1>
        <div class="greeting2 text-[100px]">
          <h2 class="text-gradient font-semibold">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="animate-fade bg-primary hover:bg-primary/90 mt-0 inline-flex h-10 items-center justify-center rounded-full border-0 bg-gradient-to-l from-blue-500 to-purple-600 px-6 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-lg transition-colors hover:from-purple-500 hover:to-blue-600"> See More </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="../Humaaans/sitting-4.svg" class="animate-fade" alt="" />
      </div>
    </article>
    <aside class="h-32 bg-amber-200"></aside>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex h-48 items-center justify-center bg-rose-200">I'm the one underneath the screen</div>



(Ensure the viewport has enough space to see the effect, and reduce the viewport height to observe the overflow effect.)
Demo on Tailwind Play
